# Statement to Count(*) related rows on other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables named `patient_list` and `dentist_list` where in the dentist can have many patients, I want to get how many patients the dentist has and ordered it.

I have here a sample code where I get each patient of doctor:

```
$query_dentist = "SELECT * FROM dentist_list ORDER BY ID ASC";
$res_dentist   = mysql_query($query_dentist);

if ($res_dentist) {
    while ($row_dentist = mysql_fetch_array($res_dentist)) {

    }
}
```

After I get all the dentists, I create a new query inside the while where I will get all the patient count.

```
$dentist_id = $row_dentist['id'];
$query_patient= "SELECT COUNT(*) as patient_num FROM patient_list
                                 WHERE dentist_id ='$dentist_id'";

$res_patient=mysql_query($query_patient);
if($res_patient)
{
     while($row_patient=mysql_fetch_array($res_patient))
     {

     }
 }
```

For example the output of query is:

```
doctor 1 has 10 patient
doctor 2 has 5 patient
doctor 3 has 100 patient
```

Rather than using PHP, is it possible to use a MySQL statement instead? I will create one query only because i need it to sort by number of patient.

Comment: Use GROUP BY statement

Comment: use GROUPBY and JOIN between two tables so that two queries and looping time will be reduced.

Comment: It is better practice to have field patient_count in dentist_list table.And update it when you add/edit/delete patient.This way you don't have to run extra query as you will have patient count for respective dentist.
Because extra group by  query will slow down the page speed when you have thousands of dentists and patients

Comment: @nedstark good indexing will solve the speed issues... No need to de normalize the database here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using this code:

```
  select d.Name, -- <- put dentist information here
         (select count(1) from patient_list p where p.dentist_id = d.dentist_id) 
    from dentist_list d
order by 2 asc -- <- order by by the 2nd field that is (select count(1...
```

Comment: :albert Daracan put code like "order by 2 asc" - order bay clause, than fiedl's number (see my edit)

Comment: It's just my habbit; the underlying reason is that count(field) counts non-nulls only; 1 can't be null, while * technically can (when all the fields within the record are null). Of course, in 99.9999% cases we can put count(*) instead of count(1)

Comment: how about to count the dentist with 0 patient.. and dentist with 1 or more than patient.. how i will query that

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Patient_Num FROM patient_list GROUP BY dentist_id ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Again... What if there is a doctor with no patients?